# Is there a universal class for bitmaps(, so it can be send from a UWP Client to a WCF Service)?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, bitmap, uwp

I want to send a bitmap from a Client (using UWP) to the Server (using WCF) using a `ChannelFactory` and a shared Interface with the `DataContract`s.

UWP doesn't support `System.Drawing.Bitmap`. The equivalent is the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap` class.

WCF supports `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, but it doesn't support `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap`.

Is there a universal class for bitmaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't a common bitmap class that you can use both in UWP and in a WCF backend. But you can just write the bitmap to a stream, transfer it in binary form (`byte[]` or `Stream`), and read it back on the other end.

Comment: So if I convert a WritableBitmap to byte[] it can be directly converted to a Bitmap? Or do I have manipulate the byte[] first?

Comment: @TobiasH, you can't really "convert" a bitmap to a byte array, but you can save the bitmap to a `MemoryStream` (or even a file stream) using `BitmapEncoder`, transmit the content of the stream to the server, which will load it with `Image.FromStream`.

Comment: In other words: don't try to send the bitmap object, send the image file instead.

Comment: You likely want a [`InMemoryRandomAccessStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.inmemoryrandomaccessstream.aspx) not a `MemoryStream` because the `BitmapEncoder` reqires a type that implments `IRandomAccessStream`.